# Python Error "TypeError: unorderable types: list() <= int()"

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, typeerror

I'm trying to develop a program, however I seem to be repeatedly greeted by the error

> TypeError: unorderable types: list() <= int()

This happens when I'm executing 2 `if` loops within each other. To give a bit of backstory into the problem, I am trying to make my program determine which *difficulty* a user has selected, and based on this, cause the program to measure a different amount of words within a file that the user has selected prior to this point.

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/RZ5uKrfx

```py
def WordCount(FileSelection):
    WrdCount = 0
    for line in ReadFile:
        Words = line.split()
        WrdCount = WrdCount + lens(Words)
    return WrdCount

def E_Mode():
    GameInitiationButton.config(state=NORMAL)
    global DifficultyState
    DifficultyState = "Easy"

def H_Mode():
    GameInitiationButton.config(state=NORMAL)
    global DifficultyState
    DifficultyState = "Hard"

def GameStage01():
    global GameStage01Button
    HardModeButton.destroy()
    EasyModeButton.destroy()
    GameInitiationButton.destroy()
    SelectTextLabel.destroy()
    SelectButton = Button(root, text='Select File', bg="grey1", fg="snow", font="consolas 9",
        command=GameStage02, height=1, width=30)
    SelectButton.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor='c')
    GameStage01Button = Button(root, text='Initiate Game!', bg="grey1", fg="snow", font="consolas 9",
        command=GameStage_E_H, state=DISABLED, height=1, width=30)
    GameStage01Button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.85, anchor='c')

def GameStage02():
    global ReadFile
    global WordCount
    FileSelection = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("*.txt files", ".txt"), ("*.txt files", "")))
    SelectTextLabel.destroy()   

    with open(FileSelection, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            WordCount = line.split()
    print(WordCount)
    GameStage01Button.config(state=NORMAL)

    # GameStage03_E()

def GameStage_E_H():
    if DifficultyState == "Easy":
        GameStage03_E()
    elif DifficultyState == "Hard":
        GameStage03_H()

def GameStage03_E():
    if WordCount <= 10:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("ERROR", " Insufficient Amount Of Words Within Your Text File! ")
```

Comment: We don't like to look up code else where, especially not large blocks.  We want to see the context of the error.  Where did the error occur, and what were you trying to do at the point.

Comment: THe error message tells me that you are trying to compare a list with a number.  You need to look at the variables where the error occurs, and determine which is the list, and which is the number.  You can do `number <= number`.  You can't do `[number, number]<=number`.

Comment: Next time, please try to construct a [mcve] that focuses on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordCount is a global variable. You assign it to the result of the split() which is a list which you then compare to a number 10 later. Essentially, you're comparing an int with a list. You should be careful on your variable names.. I would be confused by your naming conventions since there's several variables named similarly.

```
....
 with open(FileSelection, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            WordCount = line.split()
    print(WordCount)


def GameStage03_E():
    if WordCount <= 10:
```

Comment: Thank you soo much man. I cant even imagine how long it musta been for u to look through the whole program code and still help (my fault for that). I actually appreciate it so much. THank you matt. seriously. thank you.

Comment: @ArlidioDobra If an answer solved your problem, remember that you can accept an answer, if you want to. If you don't want to, that's fine too - just reminding you of the feature.